# Acid Pro 9 changed things: How to insert entire clip without dragging?

Tags: daw

I recently upgraded my DAW from Acid Pro 8 to 9. I use it for mixing a podcast. Before the upgrade I was able to drag a long audio clip (like 30 minutes and longer) onto a track and have the entire clip show up. Now the same drag only inserts one measure and I have to drag the whole clip out (like I used to have to do in the older versions of Acid Pro).

Did they just get rid of that functionality or did they hide it somehow?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because maybe this is a specific product support question, better directed at the manufacturer support service.

Answer (score 1):

The online help system was less than forthcoming the first time I looked.

1. Select Paint tool
2. Ctrl+click in the track to insert the entire media length.